# Find rows of a matrix that are linearly dependent to some other rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming, gaussian-elimination

To avoid this being an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), this is my background:

I was reading theorem 2.2.2 of section 2.2.2 of [this paper](https://www.research-collection.ethz.ch/handle/20.500.11850/167108), which is about finding a relative interior point of a system $Ax \leq b$ efficiently.

The given proof is in a constructive style as it outlines an algorithm to find one.

I could follow the proof except for the line:

> Using Gauss’ elimination algorithm we can find the index set $J \subseteq I$ of all inequalities forced to equality, given that $A_I x = b_I$.

$I$ is an already-discovered index set of inequalities forced to equality (not necessarily maximal, of course).

How do I find rest of the rows given $I$?

Comment: Basically it is the application of the complementary slackness theorem, as mentioned in the paragraph.

Comment: @callculus But how do I find other rows *other than $I$* that are forced to equality via Gauss' elimination?